# CSS-border of a certain hight

Tags: css, border

I have a website with a navigation and some borders as a devider. But I don't want the border to stretch from top 'till bottom. Any idea how to do this?

Currently, I have the first image, but I would like to make the lower one. I was thinking `padding` or `line-height`, but I'm not sure...

[image]

Comment: 2 questions: 1- Have you tried any of those options? 2- Could you provide the current code?

Comment: No, I haven't since I'm quite busy at the moment and not able to develop. And by so, I've answered you second question. I don't have access to my code at this moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use padding yes

```
.yourlink {display:inline-block;padding:10px 0; border-right: 1px solid #000;}
```

Worked out a solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/X4DZS/1/

HTML

```
<ul id="mymenu">
    <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#mymenu {display:block;height:40px;padding:10px;background-color:Green;}
#mymenu li {display:inline-block;background-color:Green;float:left;}
#mymenu a {display:block;color:#000;padding:10px;border-right:1px solid #000;height:20px;text-decoration:none;}
#mymenu li:hover {background-color: Blue;}
#mymenu li:hover a {color:#fff;text-decoration:underline;}
```

Comment: to disable last child separator do
#mymenu li:last-child a {border-right:none;}

http://jsfiddle.net/X4DZS/2/

Answer (score 1):

create a `<div>` inside another.

```
.first{
line-height:20px;
}

.second{
height:15px;
border-right:1px solid #000000;
}
```

then

```
<div class="first">
<div class="second">Test here</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest would be to use a `div` inside another `div`, the inside `div` can get the border and the outside one the padding.